# How to apply a css loader to just one specific part of content

Tags: javascript, css, classloader

I'm wondering if it's possible to apply a loader image to only a specific part of content on a webpage?

All the tutorials I've seen for loader images are for entire webpages - what I would like to accomplish is to apply a simple loader only to a div.

I'm building a website that has 2 profile images for staff members layered on top of one another, so when you hover over the image, it fades to the image at the back. I used this method because we want the smooth transition when hovering.
The only problem is that when you open the page with a slower internet speed, you see the bottom / back image until the top one loads, which is not what we want. You should only see the bottom image when you hover over the profile image.

Any ideas how I can create a loader image for only this part of the content?

Here's one of the pages on the development server: http://hanrickcurran.azurewebsites.net/tony-hunt/

Comment: This is kind of 2 questions, so you need to do 2 things. Firstly `.bottom` should be hidden by CSS so that it's never seen, despite loading order. Show it instantly prior to fading `.top` to reveal it. The second thing is your loader image. If I were you I'd add a 3rd image (the loader) to sit underneath both `.bottom` and `.top`. You don't have to worry about users seeing this loader image once top has been loaded the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the info DeeMac. I didn't even think of doing it the way you mention with hiding the bottom image until it is hovered.

I've changed the code, so now the content in the bottom / back is set to 'visibility:hidden;' and only 'visibility:visible;' when the area is hovered.